# Dúvida com nodejs: receber email

Tags: node.js

Agradeço desde já quem poder ajudar.
Estou usando esse código:

```
client.openMailbox("INBOX", function(error, info){
        if(error) throw error;
        var ex;
        client.listMessages(-10, function(err, messages){
            messages.forEach(function(message){
                console.log(message.UID + ": " + message.title);
            });
        });
});
```

Eu queria pegar o conteúdo do email e não só o titulo.
Estou a usar o modulo inbox para fazer a conexão